# create-react-native-app the system cannot find the path specified

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, cmd

Hey does anyone had the error "the system cannot find the path specified" when running the command `create-react-native-app my-app`, i have node 8.9.1 and npm 5.5.1, just to notice that create-react-app works perfectly with all the rest of the npm commands, it seems that the installation goes well `npm install -g create-react-native-app` so if anyone has any idea it would be helpful because i couldnt fix it, Thanks !

> node version: 8.9.1 npm version : 5.5.1 windows 10 x64

Comment: The error means the system couldn't find the path it was looking for, could you post a full stacktrace of the error? Maybe checkout their docs for troubleshooting tips too

Answer (score 1):

This was happened to me as same.

Finally I tried with **Windows Power Shell(x86)** & it is working for fine. But the same time with command prompt it still says "*The system cannot find the path specified*".

With using windows power shell I continue my work. Hope my comment will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what directory create-reactive-native-app was installed to after you ran

```
 npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

and add it to your path variable. When I ran the above in Command I got this output:

```
C:\Users\user>npm install -g create-react-native-app
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-native-app -> 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-native-app\build\index.js
```

So apparently it was installed to C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm, so I added it to the path by typing in Command:

```
path = %path%;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

After this I had no issues using:

```
create-react-native-app MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

uninstall create-react-app by using this command and then run npx create-react-app appname. it will work