# Facing issue while using the command "npx create-react-app"

Tags: reactjs

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

> The system cannot find the path specified.

tried to change the path through environment variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-native-app the system cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542000/create-react-native-app-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)